# MySQL: Return only results that lack specific criteria?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to construct a MySQL query that will only return unassigned tasks. A task is considered assigned when it has one or more `assignments` where `is_assignee` equals `y`.

```
tasks
- id
- name
- description
assignments
- task_id
- user_id
- is_assignee
- is_owner
```

I made the mistake of previously finding tasks that simply had no related `assignments` rows:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tasks t
LEFT OUTER JOIN assignments a
ON t.id = a.task_id
WHERE a.id is NULL
```

That worked great, but only returned tasks that had no owner AND no assignee. What I need is to return tasks that have no related `assignments` rows with `is_assignee` set to 'y'. Is there an efficient way to return only the unassigned `task` rows I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but adding additional logic to your `JOIN` clause to filter only where `is_assignee = 'y'` should do it.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tasks t
LEFT OUTER JOIN assignments a
ON t.id = a.task_id AND a.is_assignee = 'y'
WHERE a.id is NULL
```

Comment: Wow, it really was that simple. I didn't realize I could add logic to the join! Thanks a bajillion, Jason!